# Solving Lagrangian with Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm pretty new to Mathmatica but I'm trying to use it to find a Lagrangian and then find the equation of motion from the Lagrangian.

Think the method is correct but I just cant seem to get the syntax correct..
[image: Mathematica Code]

Know that it would be easier just to do this problem with pen and paper but I'm just trying to set up a script that I could use for harder problems.

Comment: Did not notice when I was reviewing it but the last bit of text is a bit wrong since I just want the differential of the partial diff.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's a specific mathematica site more suited to the subject matter (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). The tag states that fact and, in any case, this isn't really a software development question.

Answer (score 1):

Below, an example for a possible way to solve.
Note: After the lagrangian was claculated, i substituted m->1 and g-> 9.81
Hope it's useful!
Nik

[[image: Example]]